# FNR and NR variables problem

Tags: text-processing, files, awk

I have two files, one of them has 10 records, and the other one with 15 record, the problem is when I `cat` them together, always `FNR=NR`.

For example, consider below files:

File1:

```
1,boo
2,foo
3,boo
```

File2:

```
1,boo
2,foo
3,boo
4,foo
```

When applying the following code:

```
cat File1 File2 | awk -F, '{print FNR}'
```

The result should be:

```
1
2
3
1
2 
3
4
```

But what I actually have is that `FNR` = 1 to 7.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use this instead:

```
awk -F, '{print FNR}' file1 file2
```

The `FNR` variable in awk gives the number of records for each input file. But, when you use `cat .. | awk` awk reads for the stdin file descriptor, therefore awk sees only 1 "file".

Try this to understand better (`FILENAME` contains the current file being processed):

```
$ awk -F, '{print FILENAME" "FNR}' file1 file2
file1 1
file1 2
file1 3
file2 1
file2 2
file2 3
file2 4
$ cat file1 file2 | awk -F, '{print FILENAME" "FNR}'
- 1
- 2
- 3
- 4
- 5
- 6
- 7
```

As you can see in the first example, there are 2 files being processed, in the second example the `FILENAME` is `-`, indicating the standard input.

**Edit:** See the following example:

```
$ cat file1 | awk -F, '{print FILENAME" "FNR}' - file1 <(cat file1)
- 1
- 2
- 3
file1 1
file1 2
file1 3
/dev/fd/63 1
/dev/fd/63 2
/dev/fd/63 3
```

First, awk reads from the stdin (the `cat file1` part, also as a parameter `-` to awk). Then the regular `file1`. Finally the `<(cat file1)` part, which creates a pipe (`/dev/fd/63`), from where awk reads.

Comment: I concatenated the two files as below code `awk -F, '{if(FNR!=NR){print FNR}}' <(zcat File1.gz)<(zcat File2.gz)` but I got the same issue, could you advise please?

Comment: @Azizieh7 Because it's the same as `awk '{print FNR}' file1 file2`. The only difference is you read from anonymous pipes instead of regular files. The codition `FNR!=NR` is true when the file1 is processed, so `print FNR` is executed for file2.

Comment: @Azizieh7 Also, see my edit

Answer (score 3):

You concatenate (`cat`) them together, so for `awk` it is just one file (or standard input in this case). If you want to have desired result run instead

```
 awk -F, '{print FNR}' File1 File2
```

Answer (score 1):

That's not correct. When you cat the files and send them to the pipe, it's no longer counting the files separately, it's just getting all its input from the pipe as a single file.